# Link Account to activity CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm writing code that pulls from a db and populates the information as an activity, I'm successfully able to add fields from db to description and subject field, but I cant seem to get it to link to an account?
Here is what i have tried;

```
foreach (var phoneNumber in phoneNumbers)
{
    var potentialMatches = _xrm.AccountSet.Where(account => account.Address1_Telephone2.Equals(phoneNumbers)).ToList();

    if (potentialMatches.Count > 0)
    {
        var accountMatch = potentialMatches.First();

        var actualCRMAccount = (Account) _xrm.Retrieve("Account", accountMatch.Id, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true));

        if (actualCRMAccount != null)
        {
            //Is this correct way?
            new ActivityParty()
            {
                PartyId = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, actualCRMAccount.Id)
            };
            activityParties.Add(new ActivityParty() {Id = actualCRMAccount.Id});
        }
    }
}
//RegardingObjectId not working
//RegardingObjectId = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, recordRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString);
newMsg.To = activityParties;
newMsg.Description = recordRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
newMsg.Subject = recordRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

_xrm.Create(newMsg);
```

EDIT 1:
When i run it now im getting this warning

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll .
>   Additional information: The entity with a name = 'Account' was not found in the MetadataCache.

This is the piece of code where it throws the warning

```
var actualCRMAccount = (Account)_xrm.Retrieve("Account", accountMatch.Id, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true));
```

Why would this be?

Edit 2:
I replaced Account with account, see below.

```
  var actualCRMAccount = (Account)_xrm.Retrieve("account", accountMatch.Id, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true));
```

Edit 3:
Im now trying to do it for leads. but when  i add this bit of code.

```
newMsg.RegardingObjectId = activityParties;
```

I get this error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference'

How can assign a  value to `RegardingObjectId`.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: The code above is not working , the line `newMsg.To = activityParties`, does not assign the customer name to the activity?

Comment: I see you changed the posted code. Bit there´s still a problem with it:

new ActivityParty()
            {
                PartyId = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, actualCRMAccount.Id)
            };
            activityParties.Add(new ActivityParty() {Id = actualCRMAccount.Id});

should be changed to:


            activityParties.Add(new ActivityParty()
            {
                PartyId = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, actualCRMAccount.Id)
            });

This should work. If it doesn´t then probably the retrieved account does not exist.

Comment: Hi , whats id the problem?

Comment: which dll or nuget package I required for the Account.

(Account) _xrm.Retrieve("Account", accountMatch.Id, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true));

I am getting dll not found for Account entity

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you´re adding the account via: 
    new ActivityParty() { Id = actualCRMAccount.Id }

To define a new ActivityParty you must set the PartyId property which is an entity reference for the chosen Type.

```
new ActivityParty() { PartyId = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName,actualCRMAccount.Id)    }
```

should work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, so I should add your code in if statement(actualCRmAccount ! = null)

Comment: That does not have seemed to have worked for what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the following line:

```
var potentialMatches = _xrm.AccountSet.Where(account => account.Address1_Telephone2.Equals(phoneNumbers)).ToList();
```

`.Equals(phoneNumbers)` should be: `.Equals(phoneNumber)`

Then replace the code after the retrieval of the account record with this:

```
var actualCRMAccount = (Account)_xrm.Retrieve("Account", accountMatch.Id, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true));

if (actualCRMAccount != null)
{
    activityParties.Add(new ActivityParty { PartyId = actualCRMAccount.ToEntityReference() });
}
```

Comment: ,  i have add your code, its still not populating the TO, field in the form?

Comment: This should definitively work, if your retrieved account is not null. Did you check this?

Comment: There's another bug in your code. I modified my answer.